# How to configure objectMapper to not create new instance if fails?

Tags: java, json, serialization, configuration, jackson

I am using objectMapper, configured as:

```
protected ObjectMapper getCustomMapper() {
    if (this.mapper == null) {
        this.mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        this.mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        this.mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL);
    }
    return this.mapper;
}
```

And i use it like this:

```
Email email = this.getCustomMapper().readValue(jsonResponse.toString(),           Email.class)
```

My problem is that if mapping fails, then ObjectMapper returns a new email's instance with all of his attributes null. I wonder if there exists some way to tell ObjectMapper that if he can't map the json then return null, instead of a new instance of the object. Do you know how to do it? Regards

EDIT: my Json input on case success is:

```
{  
   "user_id":"542d5f15e4b090c7c78c5938",
   "email":"test@gmail.com",
   "is_primary":true,
   "is_confirmed":true,
   "creation_date":"2014-10-02T14:20:05Z",
   "id":"542d5f15e4b090c7c78c5939"
}
```

and my Json input on case fail is:

```
{  
   "code":40405,
   "message":"Email not found"
}
```

And i want that if request fails, then my email object be null. Right now, email response is not null, and all his attributes currently are.

Comment: When mapping fails the object mapper normally throws an exception. What are the input JSON look like when the mapper fails for your?

Comment: Is there another way to detect that an error occurs?. Does the jsonResponse come from a HTTP client? If so, you may get erroneous status code from the HTTP server as well, and then you could choose deserialise either the email or the error object instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather separate the deserialization of a valid email and an error objects.

It might be possible to get the status of the request from the `jsonResponse` variable mentioned in your code. So if the status code is erroneous (> 400 for HTTP requests), then the input JSON is considered as an error, otherwise it is considered as a valid email.

If the above is not possible, I would try to guess the object type based on the existence of some property. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonDetectError {
    public static final String SUCCESS_JSON = "{  \n" +
            "   \"user_id\":\"542d5f15e4b090c7c78c5938\",\n" +
            "   \"email\":\"test@gmail.com\" \n" +
            "}";

    public static final String ERROR_JSON = "{  \n" +
            "   \"code\":40405,\n" +
            "   \"message\":\"Email not found\"\n" +
            "}";

    public static class Email {
        @JsonProperty("user_id")
        public String userId;
        public String email;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Email{" +
                    "userId='" + userId + '\'' +
                    ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static class Error {
        public int code;
        public String message;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Error{" +
                    "code=" + code +
                    ", message='" + message + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    private static Object readJson(String jsonString) throws IOException {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final JsonNode json = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
        if (json.has("code")) {
            return mapper.readValue(json.traverse(), Error.class);
        }
        return mapper.convertValue(json, Email.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(readJson(ERROR_JSON));
        System.out.println(readJson(SUCCESS_JSON));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Error{code=40405, message='Email not found'}
Email{userId='542d5f15e4b090c7c78c5938', email='test@gmail.com'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jackson doesn't support this feature but you can create the custom deserializer where you can check is userName is null or not and return null object or converted object based on it. Or you can choose another field or set of fields.
In this solution you will not need to update deserializer every time you add/update/delete fields in Email class.

Custom deserializer:

```
class EmailDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Email> {

    private JsonDeserializer<Email> delegate;

    EmailDeserializer(JsonDeserializer<Email> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public Email deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        Email result = delegate.deserialize(jp, ctxt);

        if (result.getUserId() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

You need to pass delegate deserializer into the constructor if you don't want to implement full deserialization. In that case you don't need to update custom deserializer every time you change/add/delete fields from Email class. Due to you are passing constructor parameter you cannot use @JsonDeserialire annotation and you need to register it directly:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);

SimpleType simpleType = SimpleType.constructUnsafe(Email.class);
DeserializationConfig deserializationConfig = objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig();
JsonDeserializer deserializer = objectMapper.getDeserializerProvider().findTypedValueDeserializer(deserializationConfig, simpleType, null);

SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("customModuleName", Version.unknownVersion());
module.addDeserializer(Email.class, new EmailDeserializer(deserializer));
objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```